# Console.ReadLine Method in python

Tags: python

I am a total beginner to python and coding. I Was just wondering if there is a way for python to read what I've typed into the console, For example: If it prints out a question, I can answer with many choices. This is what I've tried yet.

```
`answer = input("Vilken?")
if answer.lower().strip() == "1":
    print("Okej! (1)")
elif answer.lower().strip() == "2":
    print("Okej! (2)")
elif answer.lower().strip() == "3":
    print("Okej! (3)")`
```

I got the code from a guy on youtube, for some reason, it doesn't read what I'm typing in.
I am trying to store what the player types on a variable, so I can later use it. In c# I used
`string (variable name) = Console.Readline()` If there is a way to do this is python, please let me know.

Comment: How do you know that _it doesn't read what I'm typing in_?

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: @AaronKanaron what version of python are you using

Answer (score 1):

this will solve your issue:

```
answer = raw_input("Vilken?")
if answer.lower().strip() == "1":
    print("Okej! (1)")
elif answer.lower().strip() == "2":
    print("Okej! (2)")
elif answer.lower().strip() == "3":
    print("Okej! (3)")
```

change input to raw_input

Comment: That is only in Python 2. Also if it was python 2 then ts would say that he got an error, but question claims that it just doesn't read something, so I guess there's other issue

Comment: @PavelShishmarev he didnt specify but d only problem he can have if his environment is intact would be this the use of raw_input in python2

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of the variable *`answer* to ***answer***
I think that's your problem